# Discord.py python message.content

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm making an rpgbot that is supposed to ask a few questions through DMs when creating a new character but I'm having a problem.
When I use `message.content` to get the information the bot reads messages from server instead of DMs. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

use

```
if not message.guild:
    <do stuff>
```

to ignore messages in guilds

Comment: ```if not message.guild``` just makes sure it doesnt read messages from server but it doesnt make bot read from dms

Comment: if you are using `on_message` then it should receive all messages including DMs, please add your code to your post.